# is it possible to add buttons dynamically and pass their values accordingly?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to spring technology please help to solve this problem.
I am developing a web application in spring in which I have a leaveRecords.jsp page,and It should load following things,

For each records the page should display records into the table with two buttons like

```
<button id="Accept"
         name="action"
         type="submit"
         value="Accept<%= dtoBean.getEmployee_id()/> 

<button id="Reject"
         name="action"
         type="submit"
         value="Accept<%= dtoBean.getEmployee_id()/>
```

After clicking on accept button relevant action will be performed and should redirect to same page but this time the page should contain button like

`<button id="Cancel"
         name="action"
         type="submit"
         value="Accept<%= dtoBean.getEmployee_id()` />

the **leaveRecords.jsp** is:

```
        <form:form method="POST" action="upcomingLeaves.do" commandName="loginForm" modelAttribute="loginForm">
        <% CommonDTOBean dtoBean=(CommonDTOBean)session.getAttribute("dtoBean");
            List upcomingLeavesList=(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("upcomingLeavesList");%>
    <table ><col><thead ><tr style="background-color:#666633;">
                        <th>Employee id</th>
                        <th>Leave Balance</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Leave Type</th>
                        <th>Leave Period</th>
                        <th>Applied Leaves</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th colspan="4">Action</th>
            </tr></thead>
                  <tbody>
        <%if(upcomingLeavesList!=null){
            for(int i=0;i<upcomingLeavesList.size();i++){
            dtoBean=(CommonDTOBean)upcomingLeavesList.get(i);%>
            <tr>
                <td ><span><%= dtoBean.getEmployee_id() %></span></td>
                <td ><span><%= dtoBean.getNo_of_leave() %></span></td>
                <td ><span></span><%= dtoBean.getFromDate() %>-<%= dtoBean.getToDate() %></td>
                <td > <span><%= dtoBean.getLeaveType() %></span></td>
                <td ><span></span><%= dtoBean.getLeavePeriod() %></td>
                <td><span></span><%= dtoBean.getAppliedLeave() %></td>
                <td><span></span><%= dtoBean.getLeaveStatus() %></td>
                <td><button id="btnAccept" name="action" type="submit" value="Accept<%= dtoBean.getEmployee_id() %>" onclick="">Approve</button></td>
                <td><button id="btnReject" name="action" type="submit" value="Reject<%= dtoBean.getEmployee_id() %>">Reject</button></td>
                <td><button id="btnCancel" name="action" type="submit" value="Cancel<%= dtoBean.getEmployee_id() %>">Cancel</button></td>
                </tr>
                <%}}%>
            </tbody>
  </table>
</form:form>
```

Controller class is:

```
public String ApproveLeaves(@RequestParam(required=false , defaultValue="")String aion,@RequestParam(required=false,defaultValue="")String Cancel,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model){
        try{
            //following strings are used for getting the value of button and spiting it to get employee id 

            String buttonName=request.getParameter("action");
            String buttonValue=buttonName.substring(0,6);// here we are spliting up the string and button name
            int buttonValue1=Integer.parseInt(buttonName.substring(6));

                    if (buttonValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Reject")) 
                    {

                        boolean status=LeaveStatusWorker.Approve(buttonValue1,buttonValue,dtoBean);
                        if (status) 
                        {
                                        return "redirect: GlobalConstants.UPCOMING_LEAVES";
                        }
                    }

                    if (buttonValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Cancel")) 
                    {

                        boolean status=LeaveStatusWorker.Approve(buttonValue1,buttonValue,dtoBean);
                        if (status) 
                        {

                            return "redirect: GlobalConstants.UPCOMING_LEAVES";
                        }
                    }

                    if (buttonValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Accept")) 
                    {


                        boolean status=LeaveStatusWorker.Approve(buttonValue1,buttonValue,dtoBean);
                        if (status) 
                        {

                            return "redirect: GlobalConstants.UPCOMING_LEAVES";
                        }
                    }

            return GlobalConstants.UPCOMING_LEAVES;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            return GlobalConstants.ERRORPAGE;

    }
```

service class has a method for db interaction:

```
public static boolean Approve(int id,String buttonValue,CommonDTOBean dtoBean2)
    {
        try {
            con=DBConnection.getConnection();
            String query="select no_of_leave from newemp_register where emp_id=?";//get available leaves from db
            pstmt.executeQuery();
                if(buttonValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Cancel"))
                {
                    String approve="Update newemp_register set no_of_leave=? where emp_id=?";
                    pstmt.executeUpdate();
                }
                if(buttonValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Reject"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                if(buttonValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Accept"))
                {
                        String approve="Update newemp_register set no_of_leave=? where emp_id=?";
                        pstmt.executeUpdate();
                        return true;
                    }
                }


            }//End Of while


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

return false;
    }//End of Approve
```

Please go through this example and help me I have tried very hard and searched on Google but  could not solve it.

CommonDTOBean class:

```
public class CommonDTOBean {
    private int emp_id;

    private String Status;



    public int getEmp_id() {
        return emp_id;
    }
    public void setEmp_id(int emp_id) {
        this.emp_id = emp_id;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }
```

Comment: what problem? you not able to solve.. highlight it.

Comment: @rembo,I am not able to replace button of cancel with accept and after refresh only cancel button should display.

Comment: And then If click on cancel button,then again same accept reject button should display.

Comment: ok, i think `status` field you have in `CommonDTOBean` that tells `accepted` or `rejected`? better show `CommonDTOBean` class

Comment: right.See the table contains two buttons Accept   and   Reject. If a click on accept the form will be submitted,Now,  while redirecting on same page,It should hide Accept and Reject and show 'Cancel' button...Even if I refresh the Page only cancel button should be displayed..And I am not Able to do this thing

Comment: Okay I am posting the CommonDTOBean  class right away.

Comment: @rembo,I have posted the CommonDTOBean class please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: ok, what are the possible values of `status` field? i mean when `accpted` and `rejected` like..

Comment: @rembo,values are accepted rejected and cancel.

Comment: am going to post an answer, please add complete `CommonDTOBean` clas

Comment: @rembo,I posted the class above.It has only setter and gutters methods,that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSTL](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2) for conditional rendering the DOM in jsp. like:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="upcomingLeaves.do" commandName="loginForm" modelAttribute="loginForm">        
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:#666633;">
              <th>Employee id</th>
              <th>Leave Balance</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Leave Type</th>
              <th>Leave Period</th>
              <th>Applied Leaves</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th colspan="4">Action</th>
        </tr></thead>
      <tbody>
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not empty upcomingLeavesList}">
            <c:forEach items="${upcomingLeavesList}" var="upComLeave">
                <tr>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.emp_id}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.status}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.fromDate} - ${upComLeave.toDate}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.leaveType}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.leavePeriod}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.appliedLeave}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.leaveStatus}</span></td>
                    <c:if test="${upComLeave.leaveStatus ne 'accepted' }"> //check status if accepted, don't render Accept button
                        <td><button id="btnAccept" name="action" type="submit" value="Accept${upComLeave.emp_id}" onclick="">Approve</button></td>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${upComLeave.leaveStatus ne 'rejected' }">//check status if accepted, don't render Reject button
                    <td><button id="btnReject" name="action" type="submit" value="Reject${upComLeave.emp_id}">Reject</button></td>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${upComLeave.leaveStatus eq 'cancel' }">//check status if cancel, render cancel button
                    <td><button id="btnCancel" name="action" type="submit" value="Cancel${upComLeave.emp_id}">Cancel</button></td>
                    </c:if>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            upcomingLeavesList is empty or null..
        </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
      </tbody>      
  </table>
</form:form>
```

Edit 1(based on comments):

> If I click on approve the page should redirect with only Cancel and
>   Reject button

use one more if condition like:

```
<c:if test="${upComLeave.leaveStatus eq 'accepted' }">
    <td><button id="btnReject" name="action" type="submit"  value="Reject${upComLeave.emp_id}">Reject</button></td>

<td><button id="btnCancel" name="action" type="submit" value="Cancel${upComLeave.emp_id}">Cancel</button></td>
</c:if>
```

---

Note:

add this on top of jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: ,Thank you so much for your replay and solution,But still there is a issue like

Comment: ,If I click on approve the page should redirect with  only Cancel and Reject button,This is not happning,Even if the leaveStatus is Accepted.

Comment: Also It is showing same vales in each row.for ex If I have 2 recordes in a table then Ot is fetching 1st record and displaying two times into the table,How is it possible?

Comment: check answer updated, and `It is showing same vales in each row`, check by printing the values in console if it has duplicates or not, it shouldn't print 2 times..

Comment: Yes It is showing duplicate values on console. whts wrong with this?

Comment: you should accept this as answer if it helped you(see left side one mark symbol is there), and `showing duplicate values` you should ask a new question with table details and what query you executing. and what you expecting.